# How do I put strings on a UIImageView using Objective-C (iOS)

Tags: ios, fonts, uiimageview, uiimage, font-size

I'm planning a simple drawing app for the iOS.
As i want to be able to put user defined strings with various fonts, sizes, styles (bold, italic and such) and in different colors. But I'm having no idea how this should be done. Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

> As i want to be able to put user defined strings with various fonts,
>   sizes, styles (bold, italic and such) and in different colors.

The easiest way to do that would be to place some UILabels on top of the image view. You can then set the text, size, font, color, etc. of each label as you like.

Another way is to create your own UIView subclass that draws both the image and whatever text you want.

> I'm planning a simple drawing app for the iOS....But I'm having no
>   idea how this should be done.

Start by developing a real understanding of how the view system works, how to create your own view classes, and how to draw in views. Apple provides plenty of documentation on these topics; a good starting point would be the [View Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/windowsviews/conceptual/viewpg_iphoneos/Introduction/Introduction.html).

Comment: Nevertheless, +1 for you since what you advise is helpful anyways.